# AnyLogic -- How many trips are done by my transport fleet in one hour?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I want to show on a graph how many times my "transport fleet" came to "seize transport" in one hour. The image of the complete flow is attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a variable that counts the "seizes" every time a transporter is seized

[image]

And then an event that adds the value to a dataset every hour and then resets the counter to zero

[image]

You can then display the dataset values on a chart